# How to locate installation path for software that I am able to open but I do not know the name of?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, files

The title is a bit confusing and I am a bit of a noob when it comes to linux. Basically, I have a form of qBittorrent which did not allow me to use magnet links the convenient way, I would need to copy and paste the magnet link URL. So, I was hoping to purge qBittorrent from my computer, but it did said that qBittorrent is not installed. No problem, I figured I would just install a new version on top of it, expecting this to correct anything. Now, I have 2 different qBittorrents installed, but my computer is only able to identify the one I most recently installed.

So... I am able to open / run the "older" (to me) version of qBittorrent, but it is evidently not called qBittorrent, because running `which qbittorrent` or `whereis qbittorrent` only returns the one that I recently installed.

Is it possible to identify the installation path of the "bad" qBittorrent some other way? Again, I am still able to run this program.

OS: elementary OS 6.1 Jólnir

Comment: What does the Desktop Environment have listed under Internet Applications? Is there a `Transmission` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can get the process ID (or pid) of the turkey, then, `ls -l /proc/{pid}/exe` (replacing {pid} with the pid, of course) shows the full path of the executable.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me solve the issue. I'm such an idiot... it was qbittorrent-arnatious that wasn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

It is a snap. You can list all installed packages through snap by:

```
snap list
```

You will find the exact BitTorrent client name listed.

To run it from terminal: `snap run program_name_here`. The path to installed snap is `/snap/bin`.